# Adding a class attribute to a queryset field on ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So I'm trying to add a class attribute to this field on my ModelForm to allow for Bootstrap styling:

```
category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
```

I tried this:

```
category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), widget=forms.ModelChoiceField(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

and got this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'queryset'
```

**My complete ModelForm:**

```
class NewListingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ["title", "description", "start_price", "image", "category"]


    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off', 'class':'form-control'}))
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off', 'class':'form-control'}))
    start_price = forms.DecimalField(label='Starting Bid Price (£)', widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    image = forms.URLField(widget=forms.URLInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off', 'class':'form-control'}))
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), widget=forms.ModelChoiceField(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

(I was going to do the fields = [] labels={} widgets={} format but I couldn't work out how to do that with a queryset field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`ModelChoiceField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) is a ***form field***, not a *widget*.

To update the widget class, you can follow this method,

```
class NewListingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # rest of your fields
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),

    )
    category.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

You can also change the attr by specifying a *valid widget class* as

```
class NewListingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # rest of your fields
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        # `ModelChoiceField` is using the `Select` widget bu default

    )
```

#### Reference

- [Styling widget instances--(Django Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances)